# Where is OTRS webservice endpoint?

Tags: web-services, otrs

I need to connect to the OTRS over its SOAP web service from another java application.
In the web services configuration in system administration I have configured OTRS as provider, added the operations Ticket::TicketCreate and Ticket::TicketUpdate.

My problem is I don't know how to access this web service. 
Where is the endpoint?

OTRS version used is 3.3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted my solution (in Java) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456702/otrs-error-generating-java-sei-with-wsdl/28506481#28506481)

Endpoint is http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorSOAP

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to update otrs tickets in php via soap api.

Comment: @SujanShrestha You need to a ticket search first to get the ticket you want (unless you have already know the ticket #), then use different ticketObject operation to update your tickets. http://otrs.github.io/doc/api/otrs/stable/Perl/Kernel/System/Ticket.pm.html Which version of OTRS are you using?

Comment: @wolf97084 i am using 3.1.12.. i tried using ticket object operation but its not updating it.

Comment: What error did you see? You should open another thread for your problem and upload your code. I am betting you are missing some required fields.

Comment: Hi, I added `http://www.otrs.mydomain.com/otrs/TicketConnector/` as NameSpace inside HTTP:SOAP configuration. URL `http://www.otrs.mydomain.com/otrs/index.pl/` is homepage of my OTRS page. But with this namespace configuration, I am getting HTTP 404 error when calling from remote service. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi, I added [http://www.otrs.mydomainname.com/otrs/TicketConnector/](http://www.otrs.mydomainname.com/otrs/TicketConnector/)
` as NameSpace inside HTTP:SOAP configuration. URL [http://www.otrs.mydomainname.com/otrs/index.pl/](http://www.otrs.mydomainname.com/otrs/index.pl/)  is homepage of my OTRS page. But with this namespace configuration, I am getting HTTP 404 error when calling from remote service. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If interested, the otrs SOAP endpoint for 5.0 is almost the same:

http://SERVERADDRESS/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/WEBSERVICENAME/OPERATION