# OTRS: error generating Java SEI with wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, otrs

Windows 7, Java 7
OTRS appliannce.[image]

I am trying to use wsimport to generate Java SEI with the wsdl file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OTRS/otrs/master/development/webservices/GenericTicketConnectorSOAP.wsdl

I tried from command prompt (run as admin) and it gave me errors (see attachment) and did not generate anything.

I also tried using Netbeans 8. I select create web service from wsdl file and it complains cannot find service nor port. I then validated the wsdl file, it cannot find declaration of this element, xmlns:tns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">

How am I supposed to generate SEI to talk to OTRS in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: I found other solution for generate java classes from otrs WSDL [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319442/otrs-genericticketconnectorsoap-wsdl-cant-create-port-and-service/29205592#29205592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my solution here for anyone who is interested in creating OTRS tickets from Java. I wish there is more documentation about accessing OTRS from Java.

1. Generating Java stub classes from wsdl is not possible. I cannot find any solution anywhere nor do I hear anything back from anyone here nor OTRS forums - forums.otterhub.org. (Google OTRS group wouldn't post my question.)
2. To access OTRS webservice, you will have to use SOAP. I first run SOAPRequest.pl on otrs server to get everything figured out then worked back from there. In between, I also suffered from linking namespace uri to local name problem.

My working codes are here,

```
try {
    SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection conn = scf.createConnection();
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();

    SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();
    env.addNamespaceDeclaration("tns", "http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/");
    SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
    SOAPBodyElement dispatch = body.addBodyElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "TicketCreate", "tns"));
    dispatch.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "UserLogin", "tns")).addTextNode("some user login");
    dispatch.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Password", "tns")).addTextNode("some user password");

    SOAPElement tkt = dispatch.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Ticket", "tns"));
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Title", "tns")).addTextNode("some title");
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Queue", "tns")).addTextNode("one of your queue names");
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Type", "tns")).addTextNode("one of your types");
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "CustomerUser", "tns")).addTextNode("some email address not customer id/name/username. Thought this could be my sys config");
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "State", "tns")).addTextNode("one of your states");
    tkt.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Priority", "tns")).addTextNode("one of your priorities");

    SOAPElement article = dispatch.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Article", "tns"));
    article.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Subject", "tns")).addTextNode("some subject");
    article.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Body", "tns")).addTextNode("some body");
    article.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "ContentType", "tns")).addTextNode("text/plain; charset=utf8");

    SOAPElement dynamicField = dispatch.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "DynamicField", "tns"));
    dynamicField.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Name", "tns")).addTextNode("one of your dynamic field");
    dynamicField.addChildElement(new QName("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/", "Value", "tns")).addTextNode("your dynamic field value");

    dispatch.addChildElement(tkt);
    dispatch.addChildElement(article);
    dispatch.addChildElement(dynamicField);

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    msg.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();
    URL url = new URL("http://your otrs ip address/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorSOAP");
    SOAPMessage resp = conn.call(msg, url);
    resp.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();
    } catch (SOAPException | UnsupportedOperationException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

links I referred are:

- [https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/tree/master/development/webservices](http://links%20I%20referred%20are:%20[url]https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/tree/master/development/webservices[/url]%20(Perl%20script)%20[url]https://github.com/gtudan/OTRS-Client[/url]%20(Access%20OTRA%20via%20Java%20SOAP)%20[url]http://sastriawan.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-javaxxmlsoap-to-access-otrs-soap.html[/url]%20(Access%20OTRA%20via%20Java%20SOAP)%20[url]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148081/soap-message-with-javax-xml-soap-namespace-error[/url]%20(namespace%20binding)) (Perl script)
- https://github.com/gtudan/OTRS-Client (Access OTRA via Java SOAP)
- http://sastriawan.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-javaxxmlsoap-to-access-otrs-soap.html (Access OTRA via Java SOAP)
- [SOAP message with javax.xml.soap - namespace error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148081/soap-message-with-javax-xml-soap-namespace-error)(namespace binding)